# pdoMenu (MODX) двухуровневое меню

Tags: modx, меню, revo

Есть двухуровневое меню:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Пункт</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Подпункт</li>
            <li>Подпункт</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Пункт</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Подпункт</li>
            <li>Подпункт</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Использую вывод pdoMenu:

```
[[pdoMenu?
   &limit=`10`
   &level=`2`
]]
```

На странице выводится меню в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать, чтобы подпункты не дублировались внизу?** 
Я понимаю, почему они дублируются - как этого избежать? Если с помощью pdoMenu это невозможно сделать, есть ли альтернативные способы вывода двухуровневого меню на MODX Revo?

Comment: Какой код pdoMenu?

Comment: [[pdoMenu?
   &limit=`10`
   &level=`2`
]]

Comment: По умолчанию ничего не дублируется. Хочешь чтобы ответили точней - предоставь больше информации - какова структура этих ресурсов в админке. Какой html код выводится сниппетом на странице, а не "псевдокод" того что ты хочешь получить.

Comment: Я понял, где искать. Разберусь - отпишусь. К сведению: чтобы предоставить информацию, мне нужно знать, какую именно информацию следует предоставить. Поэтому Vasis, спасибо за полезное указание, но его можно было сделать достойно и адекватно.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[!pdoMenu?
    &parents=`[[*id]]`
    &level=`2`
    &tplOuter=`@INLINE [[+wrapper]]`
    &tplParentRow=`@INLINE <ul><span>[[+menutitle]]</span>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
    &tplInner=`@INLINE <ul>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
    &tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li>[[+menutitle]]</li>`
]]
```

Вот такой вызов должен вывести пункты так как вы хотите. Возможно, у вас не дублирования, а вывод ресурсов, которые вы не ожидаете чтобы он выводил т.к. не указан параметр `&parents`. Из-за этого всякие глюки бывают!